# How do I summon something at all entities with a certain scoreboard value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friends and I are making a PVP map and we're working on the summoner/mage class, which summons things that deal damage at the position of a projectile. For testing purposes, I'm making a snowball that summons lightning at its position. I have an objective called *age* that counts up every frame for every snowball, and the lightning will only be summoned after the snowball's *age* increases to a certain value, to stop the lightning from spawning on the player and damaging them (for testing purposes, that "certain value" is 20). I have an objective called *numbers* which simply stores values (this is where the aforementioned 20 is stored). Right now, I have `execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] if score @s[type=minecraft:snowball] age > 20 numbers run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt`
but instead of summoning the lightning at the snowball, it summons it at the command block. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as` only changes the executor of the command (what `@s` is), not the position. To set the position of the command to the snowball, use `at @s`:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] at @s if score @s age > 20 numbers run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt
```

Also, you don't need `[type=minecraft:snowball]` in `if score @s[type=minecraft:snowball]` because `@s` will always be a snowball (you selected only snowballs in `@e[type=minecraft:snowball]`).

Answer (score 1):

CherryBlossom's answer is correct. I just wanted to point out another way to do it.

You can also type in the score directly in the target selector. This will save you some characters.

```
execute as @e[type=snowball,scores={age=20..}] at @s run summon lightning_bolt
```

the dots after the number 20 indicate "20 or larger".